# How to put three section inline in HTML5

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hmtl>
    <body>
        <header><h1>This is header</h1></header>
            <section id="main">
                <section id="topBlock">
                    <section id="sectionWithUList">...</section>
                    <section id="sectionWithImage">...</section>
                    <section id="anotherSectionWithUList">...</section>
                <section>
                <section id="anotherBlock">
                    ...
                <section>
            </section>
        <footer><h5>This is header</h5></footer>
    <body>
<html>
```

This is my first time that I am writing HTML5 page. I tought that it will go something like this.
Header, main section and footer. In this main section on top I have section with three sections in it (two lists and one image).
But I have a styling problem. I write css for 'topBlock' to be display:table; And three section in it to be table cell because
they need to be displayed in one row. But when I add image sections with lists in it goes too large and lists are verticaly centered.
I try to add fixed height to topBlock section but nothing helps. I need a little help to make this topBLock to have inner three section inline.

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: I don't have code with me now but basicly I put #topBlock{display: table}; and for all three inner section I put #sectionXYZ {display: table-cell};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a vertical-align to the sections.

```
#topBlock { display:table; }    
#topBlock section { vertical-align:top; display:table-cell; }
```

Answer (score -1):

In the example the sections `topBlock` and `anotherBlock` aren't closed properly, there is a section open tag where it should be `</section>`